# sql server version (11.0) is not supported

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to restore a BAK file automatically from a C# application
this is my code

```
            ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = ConnString;
            Server myServer = new Server(conn);
            myServer.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 0;
            return myServer;
```

I'm getting the following error
"
sql server version (11.0) is not supported" noting that the BAK file comes from SQLServer 2012 and I have SQLServer 2012 on the machine

Comment: are you trying to restore a backup generated by `sql server 2012` into `sql server 2008`? if so, it won't work. MSSQL is not forward compatible, only backward compatible.

Comment: no I have a BAK file from 2012 and I want to restore it into 2012 !

Comment: What is the version of the SMO classes you used to *compile* your app?

Comment: the SMO is it's 9.0.242.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SMO version 9.0.242.0 as you suggest in the above comments, that is the version for SQL Server 2005. You will need to download the correct Management Objects for SQL Server 2012.